# AFreeChart Android fullscreen view

Tags: android, charts, fullscreen, jfreechart

I have implemenented a simple chart in my app using Afreechart without any problems. 
The chart is displayed correctly fullscreen in emulator and also in my old 3,5 inch device, but if I install it in a new 5 inch smartphone then the chart occupy only half size of screen height.

```
public class ChartActivity extends Activity {

    private LinearLayout linearlayout;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is starting.
     * @param savedInstanceState
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent myIntent = getIntent(); 
        String sonda = myIntent.getStringExtra("sonda");

        EconormaChart chartView = new EconormaChart(this, sonda);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        linearlayout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.chart, null);
        linearlayout.addView(chartView);
        setContentView(linearlayout);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. It depends on the AfreeChart DemoView extended class.

```
 public class EconormaChart extends DemoView {
  }
```

Comment this lines inside DemoView class and the Chart works for ALL resolution:

```
 

       if (drawWidth < this.minimumDrawWidth) {
          this.scaleX = drawWidth / this.minimumDrawWidth;         
          drawWidth = this.minimumDrawWidth;
       }
          else if (drawWidth > this.maximumDrawWid
          this.scaleX = drawWidth / this.maximumDrawWid
         drawWidth = this.maximumDrawWidth;
       }


        if (drawHeight < this.minimumDrawHeight) {
            this.scaleY = drawHeight / this.minimumDrawHeight;
            drawHeight = this.minimumDrawHeight;
        }
        else if (drawHeight > this.maximumDrawHeight) {
            this.scaleY = drawHeight / this.maximumDrawHeight;
            drawHeight = this.maximumDrawHeight;
        }
```